# Structs with linked lst

Tags: c

I am new to C programming. I am trying to calculate the sum of the price field for each node and ended up getting a segmentation fault here. The sum should be 300 but it is giving me 100? seems like not traversing properly. Any ideas as to how to ensure this works?

Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong?

```
typedef struct Type_Of_item
{
    int item_id; // A unique identifier for each item
    char name[1024]; // The items name
    float price; // The items price
    float discount_pct; // Discount percentage in [0, .5] (0% up to 50%)
    int quantity; // Item quantity in the cart
}Item;

// The 'Item' itself contains;

typedef struct Item_Node
{ 
    Item item_info;
    struct Item_Node *next;
}node_item;

node_item *new_Item_Node(void){ // I have this also in my code pasted later

node_item *new_item=NULL;
new_item=(node_item *)calloc(1, sizeof(node_item ));



new_item->item_info.item_id=0;
strcpy(new_item->item_info.name,"");
new_item->item_info.price = 0;
new_item->item_info.discount_pct = 0;
new_item->item_info.quantity = 0;
new_item->next=NULL;

return new_item;
}
int calc_price(node_item *head){ // THIS ONE 
    node_item *p = NULL;
    p = head;
    int price;
    while (p!= NULL)
    {
        price+=head->item_info.price;
        printf("%d", item_info.price)
        p=p->next;
        
    } 
return price;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    node_item *product1 = NULL; 
    node_item *product2 = NULL;
    node_item *product3= NULL;
    node_item* head = NULL;
    

    product1 ->item_info.item_id=22;
    strcpy(product1->item_info.name,"");
    product1->item_info.price = 100;
    product1->item_info.discount_pct = 0.5;
    product1->item_info.quantity = 2;
    product1->next=NULL;

    product1 ->item_info.item_id=33;
    strcpy(product1->item_info.name,"");
    product1->item_info.price = 200;
    product1->item_info.discount_pct = 0.8;
    product1->item_info.quantity = 3;

    head = product1;
    float result = calc_price(head); // fcn call 
    printf("%f",result);

}
```

Comment: statements like this product1 ->item_info.item_id=22; invoke undefined behavior because product1 is a null pointer. You need to allocate an object of the type node_item to which the pointer will point to.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you give an example please?

Comment: For example you could write node_item product1; Then fill data members of the object and then write node_item *head = &product1;

Comment: Pay attention to that the function calc_price does not make a sense. At least you should initialize the variable price by zero. int price = 0;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Bigger problem is in the line `printf("%d", item_info.price)`. A semicolon is missing and undeclared `item_info` is used.

Comment: I tried it works but it still gives me 100 and it should return 100+200 = 300 seems like it is not traversing properly.

Comment: When calculating a sum it is customary to use addition somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated the memory for your struct

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    node_item *product1 = NULL; 
    node_item *product2 = NULL;
    node_item *product3= NULL;
    node_item* head = NULL;


    product1 = malloc(sizeof node_item); // add this
    product2 = malloc(sizeof node_item); // add this
    product3 = malloc(sizeof node_item); // add this
```

Comment: I have actually I did paste that portion but i did allocate memory  node_item *new_Item_Node(void){

node_item *new_item=NULL;
new_item=(node_item *)calloc(1, sizeof(node_item ));


new_item->item_info.item_id=0;
strcpy(new_item->item_info.name,"");
new_item->item_info.price = 0;
new_item->item_info.discount_pct = 0;
new_item->item_info.quantity = 0;
new_item->next=NULL;

return new_item;
}

Comment: so, you should not leave product1 until product3 not null. product1 = new_Item_Node(); product2 = new_Item_Node(); product3 = new_Item_Node();